# Full node disconnected in a whole country

Tags: ethernodes

Why is it important to have at least a few full nodes running in a specific country? Does e.g. Spain have any advantage to run ETH full nodes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that's a matter of opinion. Some might claim that it's not important where the nodes are as long as they are decentralized.

However it might not be a bad idea to have at least a few (full) nodes running in any given geographical region, mostly for latency. The further you are from the node you use the more latency you have and the more difficult it might be for you to mine successfully.

Anyway, as I said, I don't think there are strict reasons why a node should exist in a given geographical location. At least I can't think of many.